# Create new array from existing one only with elements that contain specific value

Tags: javascript, arrays, key-value

I create a new array from an existing one *(big array with 100.000 objects)*. In the new array I want only elements where the value of "city" is for example New York City.

```
    var newData = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        if(data[i].city === "New York City") {

            newData[i] = {"city": data[i].city, "longitude": 
            data[i].longitude, "latitude": data[i].latitude, "state": 
            data[i].state};

        }
     }
```

I must be doing something wrong since a lot of elements in the new array are `null` …

The new array then looks something like this:

```
[null,null,null,null,null, {"city":"New York", "logitude": 
-73.935242, "latitude": 40.730610, "state": "NY"},
null,null,null,null,null,null,"city":"New York", "logitude": 
-73.935242, "latitude": 40.730610, "state": "NY"}]
```

What am I doing wrong? How could I achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Why not use `filter`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox: Looks like they want to create new objects.

Comment: You could try using console.log(data[i]) inside the if statement, to see what part of the object is being outputted. Excluding the null result, does the new array contain all the correct results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The elements won't be `null`, they'll be *missing* (which shows up as `undefined` when you try to access them). The reason is that you're increasing `i` every time, even when you skip an entry.

To fix it, use `push` instead:

```
var newData = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    if (data[i].city === "New York City") {
        newData.push({
            "city": data[i].city,
            "longitude": data[i].longitude,
            "latitude": data[i].latitude,
            "state": data[i].state
        });
    }
}
```

**If** you want the two arrays to *share* objects, you could use `filter` instead:

```
var newData = data.filter(function(entry) {
    return entry.city === "New York City";
});
```

**but** if you want the new array to have new objects that are different from the originals, your `for` loop is fine.

Comment: I am so blind … Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```
newData.filter(function (el) {
  return el.city === "New York City";
});
```

or if you need other filter parameter:

```
newData.filter(function (el) {
  return el.city === "New York City" && el.state === "NY" ;
});
```

This method is part of the new [ECMAScript 5th Edition standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).

From documentation:

> `filter()` calls a provided callback function once for each element in
>   an array, and constructs a new array of all the values for which
>   callback returns a value that coerces to true. callback is invoked
>   only for indexes of the array which have assigned values; it is not
>   invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been
>   assigned values. Array elements which do not pass the callback test
>   are simply skipped, and are not included in the new array.